# How get a custom UITableViewCell to appear in a UITableView in custom UIViewController with storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I think I"m really close now, but I'm missing something.  If I break before I return the cell in the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath method, the cell is holding the correct data.  But it doesn't appear in the table.  I'm assuming that my UITableView is not hooked up to the UIViewController properly.

Here is my custom cell: SCCustomerTableCell.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SCCustomer.h"

@interface SCCustomerTableCell : UITableViewCell

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *companyLabel;
-(void)configureCellWithCustomer:(SCCustomer *)customer;

@end
```

SCCustomerTableCell.m

```
#import "SCCustomerTableCell.h"

@implementation SCCustomerTableCell

-(void)configureCellWithCustomer:(SCCustomer *)customer
{
    self.companyLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    self.companyLabel.text = [customer dbaName];
}

@end
```

And the custom view controller: SCCustomersVC.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SCCustomerTableCell.h"
#import "SCDataObject.h"

@interface SCCustomersVC : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *customersTable;
@property SCDataObject *dataObject;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *customers;

@end
```

SCCustomersVC.m

```
#import "SCCustomersVC.h"
#import "SCSplitVC.h"
#import "SCDataObject.h"

@interface SCCustomersVC ()
@end

@implementation SCCustomersVC

@synthesize customersTable;

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.customers count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomerCell";
    [self.customersTable registerClass:[SCCustomerTableCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    SCCustomerTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    SCCustomer *customer = (SCCustomer *)[self.customers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell configureCellWithCustomer:customer];
    return cell;
}
```

Edit: I forgot screens of storyboard connections:
[SCCustomersVC](http://screencast.com/t/WqiqGiROyQwN), [UITableView](http://screencast.com/t/xM8KhqmROD), [SCCustomerTableCell](http://screencast.com/t/Ksv9Z0v9z6Hj), [UILabel](http://screencast.com/t/N6a3VDk8ToY6)

Comment: Did you set SCCustomerVC as the data source and delegate of the table? Also, you shouldn't register the class in the cellForRowAtIndexPath -- it's called many times, and you only need to register once. Better to do it in viewDidLoad.

Comment: I believe they are set correctly via storyboard.  I added screen shot links.  Noted about registering the class.  Thanks.

Comment: They are now, but they weren't when I first looked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, there are several things you're doing wrong. I see from your screen shots that you didn't set your controller as the data source or delegate of the table view. You need to do that. Second, if you make the custom cell in the table view in IB, you don't need to register the class, just make sure that you have the identifier set. Third, since you made the label in IB, and you have an outlet to it, you don't need to alloc init it in your cell's .m file -- in fact you don't need anything at all in the .m . Just put cell.companyLabel.text =... in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method.